# ConfigurationsContainer is empty in multi-project setting

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-project setting in my Android project:

```
- android
  - app
  - lib1
  - util
```

In `util` I defined a configuration:

```
task createTestJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'test'
    from "$projectDir/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug"
}

configurations {
    archives
    archives.transitive =  true
}

artifacts {
    archives createTestJar
}
```

And I tried to reference it in `lib1`:

```
// doesn't work
testCompile project(path: ':util', configuration: 'archives')
```

I get this error for the above line:

> Error:com.android.builder.dependency.level2.JavaDependency cannot be cast to com.android.builder.dependency.level2.AndroidDependency Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all  Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>     -Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

```
// says can't find 'archives' in configuration container
testCompile project(':util').configurations.archives.artifacts.files
// works if I manually create the jar beforehand
testCompile fileTree(dir: "$rootDir/utils/build/libs", include: ['*.jar'])
```

I tried to print out what configurations my `util` module has in `lib1`:

```
project(':util').configurations.forEach {
    println("${it.name}")
}
```

And I get empty result. When I print it in my `util` module I can see a long list, with my `archives` config in it.

Any idea why this happens? I heard there's some default tasks that comes with the `java` plugin which android doesn't have? BTW both `lib1` and `util` has these plugins applied:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Comment: You call the project `util`, but in your code you use `utils` and `shared-utils`. Is this a simple typo in the post or does it also appear in your code? Principally your first example should be correct, maybe you could specify how it does not work, if the typo should not be the only reason. Both your second example and your debug code suffer the same problem, the order of execution. If the *configuration phase* (and therefor the build file evaluation) of your `util` project comes after the one of your `lib` project, the configurations won't exist, since they are created once you apply plugins.

Comment: @lu.koerfer oops they're typos. They're actually all `shared-utils` in my repo and I forgot to rename some of them when copying over. I've added the err message for the first example! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, turns out I missed this line in the `android {}` block:

`publishNonDefault true`